# WordPress page cached, not loading new .txt data in page

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, cdn, cloudflare

Dear Stackoverflowers,

Currently I'm working on a webpage that should load data from a .txt file containing data.
The text file is: https://proranje.nl/laatste_zoek_data.txt

I have written a program that writes values to the .txt file, than redirects you to the following page: https://proranje.nl/hoeveel-is-mijn-huis-waard/ and that page loads the content from the .txt file as following through the wordpress functions.php file:

```
function uitslag_van_bepaling() {
    $tekst = file_get_contents('https://proranje.nl/laatste_zoek_data.txt');
    $tekst = explode('###', $tekst);
    $postcode = $tekst[0];
    $huis_nummer = $tekst[1];
    $zelf_m2 = $tekst[2];
    $verhuurd = $tekst[3];
    $status = $tekst[4];
    $bod_waarde = $tekst[5];
    $bod_1pct = $bod_waarde/100;
    $bod_95 = $bod_1pct*95;
    $bod_105 = $bod_1pct*105;

    $bod_waarde = nummerform($bod_waarde);
    $kadaster_waarde = $tekst[6];
    $kadaster_m2 = $tekst[7];
    $fixed_html = '';
    $fixed_html .= '<div id="waarde_bod"><div id="top_waarde"><strong>Postcode: </strong><span>'.$postcode.'</span>, <strong>Huisnummer: </strong><span>'.$huis_nummer.'</span></div><div class="fix50"><h3>&euro; '.nummerform($bod_95).'</h3><span>Lage schatting</span></div><div class="fix50"><h3>&euro; '.nummerform($bod_105).'</h3><span>Hoge schatting</span></div></div>';
    return $fixed_html;
}
```

The website is being loaded through Cloudflare CDN and I have tried disabling the page cache so it gets reloaded every time but nothing seems to help. Is there someone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the text file stored under a different domain - or why is this an HTTP request in the first place, instead of reading the file contents via the local file system?

Comment: Ah.. does that make a difference in cache you think?

Comment: How did you disable the page cache?

Comment: Cache has been disabled with the hummingbird exclude settings, the pages calculating the price are excluded from caching. aswell as I have added this code to the functions.php:  if ( is_page('hoeveel-is-mijn-huis-waard')) {
  define('DONOTCACHEPAGE', true);
 }

Comment: Btw update for topic: $tekst = file_get_contents('./laatste_zoek_data.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH); had no effect, Before you are redirected, the new data (Which is not loaded in: /hoeveel-is-mijn-huis-waard/) is visible in: https://proranje.nl/laatste_zoek_data.txt but still does not load the correct values.

Comment: The solution which has helped for me was refreshing the page making it load new cache based on the adres searched. added an hashtag #Postcode-Number behind the url after 0,5 seconds on visiting the page. Problem has been solved.